# How Can I See The Entire Array When Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

When I hover over an stl container, I can instantly get a snapshot of its contents:

[image]

However, if I for example, have a class with m_array which is allocated as new int[99]; then I only see the first integer of that array when I hover.

I find this inconvenient for debugging.

How can I make my class display its array's contents when I hover over it when debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to do that, as far as I know. You can however go around this using the watch variables box, type name of your array, size of array. For example

`myArray,100` shows 100 elements of array myArray.